# How SHA-RSA works?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, sha

Sorry for my noob question, i'm new in this field (but i'm curious).
I've found an xml file with two fields: DATA and SIGNATURE.
DATA is an Ascii text, SIGNATURE is an SHA1-RSA1024 string composed by 256 hex characters (128bytes). 
I don't understand how can bi obtained that signature from the data field: the data is elaborated with the RSA and then with SHA or it is the contrary?
I'm studying RSA and i think i should find something like this:

```
00 01 FF FF .. FF FF 00 DigestInfo MessageDigest
```

But it is not true: my signature data doesn't contain that string.
Can you explain me the procedure used to obtain the signature?
Do you have a link with an example (maybe in Python, due to its simplicity)?

Comment: Have a look here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9260/sha-rsa-and-the-relation-between-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [security.stackexchange.com answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9260/sha-rsa-and-the-relation-between-them) has pretty good detail, but here's the short form (since they don't seem to *quite* answer your question.

The first step is [EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-9.2), where `M` is the (unhashed) message and `emLen` is the size (in bytes) of the RSA key (which is usually expressed in bits).

`H` = `Hash(M)`. We know `Hash` is `SHA-1` (by the question), so the output is 20 bytes.  Let's assume it produced `20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20`.

Construct `T`:

```
// DigestInfo = SEQUENCE(AlgorithmIdentifier, OCTET STRING)
30 21
   // AlgorithmIdentifier = SEQUENCE(OBJECT IDENTIFIER, ANY)
   30 09
      // OBJECT IDENTIFIER(SHA1) => OBJECT IDENTIFIER(1.3.14.3.2.26)
      06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A
      // NULL (SHA-1 has no parameters)
      05 00
   // OCTET STRING(H)
   04 14 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

Since everything in this structure has fixed values (SHA-1 OID) and/or length (H=20 bytes) T is just (`30 21 30 09 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A 05 00 04 14` concat `H`) (for SHA-1).

Let's assume we have a 2048-bit key (256 bytes).  Since tLen=35, emLen > tLen + 11, so we're good to proceed.

Now, build `PS`. It is `emLen - tLen - 3` `FF`.  For SHA-1 with RSA-2048 that means a sequence of 218 `FF`s.

```
EM = 00 01 PS 00 T
```

Gluing everything together now, we get (for SHA-1 and a 2048-bit key)

```
00 01 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 30 21 30
09 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A 05 00 04 14 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

As you can see, the hash output is still visible, at the very end.  The EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 padded structure seems to be what you expected.

Then, `EM` gets applied through the RSA private key formula to produce the signature:

```
`signature` = MODPOW(`EM`, `d`, `n`)
```

Since the value of `signature` now depends on `d` (the private key) no fixed example can be given.  But this last step is why a) it's cryptographically sound, and b) you can't find your `MessageDigest` value within the signature value anymore.

For RSA signatures the signature gets verified as

```
`candidate` = MODPOW(`signature`, `e`, `n`)
return ConstantTimeSequenceEquals(`candidate`, `EM`);
```

The new RSA signature algorithm (PSS (Probabilistic Signature Scheme)) works quite differently.  And, it's worth noting, DSA and ECDSA work even more quite differently.